# How to get locale from keycloak with keycloak-js

Tags: reactjs, frontend, localization, keycloak, keycloak-js

**Problem:** There is no information in the keycloak documentation how to get locale information (which language was selected in the locale selector in the keycloak login page) in your app, after successfully logging in.

[image]

There is one place in the docs about localization (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#enabling-internationalization) but it is not what i needed.

PS. I'm using keycloak-js lib.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** 1) In the place where you init your app:

[image]

2. After successful initialization, you can get parsed token:

[image]

And in that **tokenParsed** there is field named "locale"

[image]

Here is **how to get parsed token** in keycloak-js:

[image]
[image]